# How to Block Access to EC2 Instance Public IP Address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using the Django framework on Elastic Beanstalk and I have been getting many requests from bots trying to find security vulnerabilities. The server always responds with a 400 because they access the IP address of the EC2 instance and the IP address is not in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list.

Is there a way to block access to the instance through its public IP address and only allow access to it through the domain I assigned to it?

Comment: Yes. Use load balancer in front of your instance.

Comment: @Marcin I do have a classic load balancer. How can I prevent access to the public IP address of the instance with a load balancer?

Comment: You can also use WAF and CloudFront. It really depends on your budget, but security is an absolute must-have investment

Comment: SG of your instances should allow only inbound traffic from CLB's SG.

Comment: @Marcin thank you, it worked! So it doesn't let me access the instance by its public IP that I can see in my EC2 dashboard. If I type `host mydomainname.com` in bash, it shows me 2 IP addresses that if I try to access, return 400 code too as before. How can I prevent that? What are these IP addresses of?

Comment: These are nodes of your CLB most likely.

Comment: @Marcin How can I block access to the public IP addresses of the nodes of my classic Load Balancer? Thanks so much for all your help, BTW!

Comment: You can't. Its AWS responsibility to worry about these nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the solution was to setup security groups in such a way that instances only allow inbound traffict from the CLB's security group.

More about this setup can be found below:

- [Configure Security Groups for Your Classic Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-groups.html)